# CI job fails because of custom docker runner has no elevated priveleges

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use a custom docker runner in my CI jobs. During the execution of the job, the following error occurs:
[image]

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You either do not have docker engine installed and running on your system or the user you are using to run the gitlab-runner process or service does not have permissions to access the docker named pipe file (socket).

To fix it, make sure:

1. The docker engine is installed and running (e.g., docker desktop/engine is running and available)
2. If you are using the standalone executable `gitlab-runner`, make sure the user you are using to run the command has permissions to the docker socket (the user should be a member of the `docker-users` group or be run as the builtin System account).
3. If you are using the Windows service integration for the GitLab runner, open `services` then find the runner service, right-click and select `properties` -- under the `log on` tab, ensure the user is set to System or a user account with sufficient privileges to access the docker socket.